# Separate Date and time with " (String.Format)" in R?

Tags: r, string, date

Is it possible to separate Date?

So it would be that "YYYYMMDD" just like "20170831".

How to convert "20150101" to "2015-01-01", thanks.

```
A <- data.frame(Item_A = c("00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00FR", 
            "00FR"),Item_B = c("JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", 
            "JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", "RICE MIDSTREAM", "RICE 
             MIDSTREAM"), 
            DATE = c("20150101", "20150102", "20150103", "20150104", 
            "20150105", "20150106", "20150107"))
```

EXPECT:

```
A <- data.frame(Item_A = c("00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00FR", 
            "00FR"),Item_B = c("JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", 
            "JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", "RICE MIDSTREAM", "RICE 
             MIDSTREAM"), 
             DATE = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-
             04","2015-01-05", "2015-01-06", "2015-01-07"))
```

Comment: `as.Date(A$DATE, format = "%Y%m%d")` ?

Comment: No, I try as.Date, before asking. but It can not work.

Comment: It works for me. What is the error message that you get ?

Comment: I know what the error was. See my answer.

Comment: Do you really want `DATE` to be returned as character vector as shown in your expected result? Or, do you want `DATE` to be of *class* Date? So either is the accepted answer wrong or your expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
A %>%
  mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE))
```

Comment: Hi,  your code is good I like it, but I have a question that ymd packegart is "lubridate", right?

Comment: @YXCHEN Yes, it is from lubridate

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anytime`

```
A$DATE <- anytime::anytime(A$DATE)
```

(no need to load the whole universe)

---

If `A` is a large dataframe, we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[, DATE := as.IDate(DATE, "%Y%m%d")][]
```

which updates *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole data object in order to safe memory and time.

---

**Note** that both approaches convert the `DATE` column to *class `Date`*. The expected result given by the OP shows `DATE` as *character string*. So, if the OP really expects character strings as output `DATE` needs to be converted a second time using `format(A$DATE)`, e.g.

Comment: wOW~ THANKS A LOT.

Comment: setDT() is really a good funtion.

Comment: Yes, it coerces a data.frame or tibble to class data.table *without* copying the whole object. BTW, there is also a counter-part, `setDF()`.

Comment: I have a question. when I used the code "setDT(A)[, DATE := as.IDate(DATE, "%Y%m%d")][]" in my data, and then It shows that Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format. why?

Comment: Looks like `Date` is not in `YYYYMMDD` format. What does `str(A)` return?